# How can I retrieve/ store the content of a HTML site after the javascript has been executed in it, in a python variable?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and I've only been able to find related articles/posts of this matter which are severely outdated.

I want to read and store the content of a webpage in a variable in Python. This I can manage, but the javascript generated content isn't stored because the script has not been executed yet. Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the site content AFTER the javascript has been run?

Comment: `Selenium` has [options](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for a certain element to be loaded.

Comment: You can't retrieve the content after javascript has run, JS is client-side, so you need to retrieve the JS then run it.

Comment: @JeffUK Is it possible to code that in Python?